# Weird text behaviour in d3js after update function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bno5106ho1kYLnYMl1c4?p=preview) after you've updated the chart, the percentage that's displayed is completely wrong.
The displayed percentage before the update is however correct and I have no idea as to why this is .

Here's part of the code that isn't behaving as expected.

```
label.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .text(function(d) { 
        return textFormat(100/(d.data.total/d.data["apples" + CAT]))+'%'});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only ever calculate `d.total` for category `one`.  In your update function you need to rerun:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.total = d3.sum(data, function(d) { return d3.sum([d["apples" + CAT]]); });
});
```